# How can I globally block Gerrit submits while I'm force-push changes?

Tags: git, gerrit, githooks

We are migrating from Perforce to Git/Gerrit, but still depend on keeping our Git repository in sync with a secondary Perforce repository. Due to how this is all glued together, we do occasionally have to force push changes to our Gerrit repository. In general this works fine.

However, we do occasionally experience that a review is submitted from Gerrit in the interval between a fetch and the subsequent force push, and hence gets silently dropped.

Is there any good way for us to disable submits from Gerrit while we're force-pushing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily revoke the Submit permission(s) in the ACLs for the affected projects, see the [access control documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_submit). That permission is usually set in the All-Projects git and not overridden or amended in child projects so it should be an easy change to make.